# Convert timestamp to date hql for sybase database

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am using *Sybase* database and I want to fetch a timestamp field as a date. How can I use a timestamp field as a date in *HQL*?

My query:

```
SELECT new map(NAME,SUM(MARKS),ADMISSIONDATE) 
FROM STUDENT 
GROUP BY NAME,MARKS,ADMISSIONDATE
```

, where ADMISSIONDATE is a timestamp in the database.

I want to ignore time in my query.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show your entity, your query, and tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: My query looks like "SELECT new map(NAME,SUM(MARKS),ADMISSIONDATE )FROM STUDENT GROUP BY NAME,MARKS,ADMISSIONDATE" where ADMISSIONDATE is timestamp in database and i want to ignore time in my query

Answer (score 0):

Think the easiest way is to map *TIMESTAMP* column in Sybase to *java.sql.Date* into STUDENT entity. Hibernate [should map](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes) TIMESTAMP column into appropriate date type:

> **date, time, timestamp**
>
> Type mappings from [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and its subclasses to SQL types DATE, TIME and TIMESTAMP (or equivalent).

Some suggestion: Use named parameters in [new map(...)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select)

Answer (score 0):

use convert methods

for ex:

convert(varchar(12),ADMISSIONDATE,109) which will returns the out put as 'Jul 24 2013'